String to byte Array without encoding in Java
I am using com.google.protobuf.ByteString and trying to serialize it so I can store it as a string.
String value = Arrays.toString(byteString.toByteArray());

Now I want to reverse it and change it back into a byteString.
byte[] byteArray = value.getBytes(); ??
ByteString.copyFrom(byteArray);

I doubt this is going to work. An example of a ByteString in string format using the first line above looks like this [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -118, 7, -52, 0, 0]. Which is fine, I don't mind storing this. It seems like these characters are represented entirely as numbers. Now I want to reverse it so I can recreate a ByteString. The problem is I do not know how to convert it back into a byte array and undo Arrays.toString(byte[]).
I do not know the encoding on the byte array originally. Its from saleforce replay id. I also do not have an easy way to store it as byte data. Is there some fancy Arrays.UndoString() or do I have to write my own function?

I think, firstly, you should test your code to see if it works.  Posting untested code rather disrepects the time of anyone trying to answer.  However, for this case, I'd consider defining my own class that has both a Java string and also the original byte string.  This avoids the problem of having to translate it back.  class MyString { private String s; private ByteString b; //etc. }

@markspace its more of a question of how to undo Arrays.toString(byte[]). I was just giving some sample code for an idea. There is no way that string.getBytes() will work because it uses default encoding.

@markspace making a class won't solve my problem of serializing the byte array. I need to store it as a string. I also need to deserialize it.

Your com.google.protobuf.ByteString is in fact Serializable so your most lossless approach would be to serialize it and then apply one of @Sören's alternatives to it. In that way, you can realize your ambition of Now I want to reverse it so I can recreate a ByteString.

Arrays.toString isn't really meant to be undone. Sure you could write a parser for it. But why would you, if there are alternatives available?
Alternative 1: Base64
Use
import java.util.Base64;
Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(yourarray)

to convert your array into a string and
Base64.getDecoder().decode(yourstring)

to get the array back.
Alternative 2: JSON
Results in more readable Strings, but requires an external library of which there are many. Therefore I won't give any example code here.

Base64 encoding might work. I will give it a try.

Most embeddings of byte arrays are going to be BaseSomething -- the most common one is Base16.

Yeah this worked, I feel dumb for not thinking of this.
